# fadeIn DIV affecting other div values

Tags: jquery, css, html, fadeout

I'm new to jquery and javascript in general so I'm having some trouble figuring things out. Right now, I want an image to animate downward (iphone) while an image fades in (shadow) while another image animates upwards (reflection) while fading in. The code I have now just fades everything in at the same speed (doesn't matter if each div has different time values). Also, if I try to animate the reflection, it just pulls all the elements down (if I edit the start value of the div). This is probably because the reflection is the first element in the "wrap" div. I can't really change this because I want the iphone overlapping the shadow which overlaps the reflection. So, I need to initiate the reflection div first (I tried using z values which didn't work). Any tips? Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 

  <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel=StyleSheet href="external_style_sheet.css" type="text/css">

  <script type="text/javascript">

     $(function() {
        $('#iphone').animate({"top" : "1000px"}, 1200);
        $('#shadow').fadeIn(1800);
        $('#reflection').fadeIn(1800);

     });

  </script>
</head>

<body id="index" class="home">


<div id="wrap" > 
   <div id="left" />  
   <div id="right" >
      <div id="reflection" />
      <div id="shadow" />
      <div id="iphone" />
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS

```
    `p {font-family: georgia, serif; font-size: x-small;}
hr {color: #000000; height: 1px }
a:hover {color: #ff0000; text-decoration: none}

body {
  background-color:#1b1a1f;

}



#reflection {
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  position:relative; 
  width: 414px;
  height: 993px;
  background-image: url("images/reflection2.png");
  display: none;
  z-index: -1;

}

#shadow {
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  position:absolute; 
  width: 414px;
  height: 818px;
  background-image: url("images/shadow3.png");
  display: none;
  z-index: 1; 
}


#iphone {
  margin-top:-1000px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  position:relative; 
  width: 414px;
  height: 818px;
  background-image: url("images/iphone_2.png");
  z-index: 0;
}



#wrap {
  width:800px;
  margin:0 auto;
  background-image: url("images/logo.png");
}


#left {
  float:left;
  width:500px;
}

#right {
  float:right;
  width:500px;

}

HTML
<div id="bar">Content</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues here, though I think you're close...

- make sure your HTML is well-formed and that div elements open and close
- don't use a z-index of -1, use only positive values for each element (I usually space them out by 5 or so levels)
- apply "position: relative;" to #right, manually set the height and width, and then make #reflection, #shadow, and #iphone all "position: absolute;" so everything doesn't shift around while animating (just make sure this works with your page layout)

Comment: Thanks! I closed the div elements separately and it changed the placement of the divs completely - so, I changed the css to adjust the positioning. It all seems to work out in a make-shift way but the reflection now fades-in and then animates upwards - I tried the 
solutions I found online but combining both into one "animate"
function makes all the div elements disappear completely. Any ideas?

Here's the code:

Comment: You might post a demo of this; it's becoming tough to see what's going on or make any suggestions.

Comment: Heres the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Rzbb7/

if you need the pictures, I can send them by email

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance you can post the whole thing (HTML + CSS + JS) somewhere with images? Better public so that others can examine and answer.

Comment: I put everything in a rar: http://lts.cr/rf9

Let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: Okay, this was sort of a mess and I feel kind of dirty having taken it this far. I basically followed through on my own suggestions with this example. You can't use animate() and fadeIn() at the same time, and you need to be deliberate when using relative vs. absolute positioning. Hopefully all other answers reveal themselves. I changed the jQuery reference and moved styles inline for simplicity.

http://wrkcpt.com/2H0C110a0P2i2F2m2X1j

Comment: Wow thanks a lot! I'll see what you changed and hopefully learn for next time.